# C# verificar "null" ou "NaN" ou "false" ou "0"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockoutjs

Estou com uma dificuldade de validação. Tenho uma `View` que envia para o `Controller` informações, onde na `view` é utilizado `knockoutjs`, porém tem hora que ele envia um `null` ou `"null"` ou `"NaN"` ou `"false"` ou `"0"`, só não vi `"undefined"` ainda!

Parte do Script `knockoutjs` quando não tem informação:

```
  var InternalAuditRecordTopicEmpty = {
            InternalAuditRecordTopicID: 0,
            InternalAuditRecordID: 0,
            Name:'',
            Order:9999,
            Request:'',
            NonComformityType:'',
            Comformity:'',
            OM:'',
            Observation:'',
            Evidences:'',
        };
```

Meu Controller:

```
     if (criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM == "false"   
        || criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM == "0")  
                                   criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM = null;

if (criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM == null && iscontrol)
                        { error =true; }
```

Minha duvida é: tem como eu fazer algo genérico ou tenho que verificar um por um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso

```
        string[] ElementAt = { "null", "NaN", "false", "0", "undefined", null };
        string erro = null;

        foreach (var item in ElementAt)
        {
            if (erro == item)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ops, um erro aconteceu!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu fiz assim para tentar resolver essa problema:

Criei um Método:

```
 public string ValidNull(string val)
        {
            switch (val)
            {
                case "null":return null;
                case "NaN": return null;
                case "false":return null;
                case "0":return null;
                case "undefined": return null;
                default:return val;
            }

        }
```

Utilizei da seguinte forma:

```
    criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM =  
 ValidNull(criticalAnalysisRecord.InternalAuditRecordTopics.ElementAt(i).OM);
```